# NATO command -- mass noun?

Tags: grammar

Example with a context ([Putin's dream of reuniting the Russian empire is falling apart](http://www.businessinsider.com/putin-puts-novorossiya-project-put-on-hold-2015-5)):

> **NATO command** has openly accused Moscow of sending troops and equipment (including tanks and heavy artillery) across the border to support the Russian-speaking rebels against the government in Kiev.

Why is there no definite article in front of *NATO command* and what does *command* really mean in this context? Although I'm not one hundred percent sure, I think I may have sort of a gut feeling that this might be something along the lines of when we say *New York police* to mean a bunch of police officers with *New York* serving as an adjective and the whole thing working as a mass noun. For example:

> Weightlifting is a very common past-time activity among *New York police*.

Are the two phrasings structurally and grammatically similar? Do you think I'm on the right track with this?

Comment: I feel like it's almost more of a proper noun...

Comment: Yes you're on the right track. The constructions are structurally and semantically similar.  As you showed by example, you don't need a definite article with _New York Police_; likewise, you don't need one with _NATO command_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Command" is a count noun. From [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/command_1):

> 5. military [C also + plural verb British English]
>      
>    b) a group of officers or officials who give orders: *the Army High Command*

But, in the example "NATO command" is an entity... much like "New York Police". It's also being used in news, which gets away with dropping articles, particularly in headlines. News writing is its own little world to some degree but it's perfectly acceptable to write it as it is.

In fact, "NATO command" sounds more correct to me than "New York police". In your second sentence, I would actually prefer that it read:

> Weightlifting is a very common past-time activity among New York police **officers**.

Because, to me, "New York police" should imply the actual *entity*, like [here](http://pix11.com/2015/02/16/man-slashes-womans-face-on-lower-east-side/):

> New York Police are looking for a man accused of slashing a woman’s face with an unknown object on the Lower East Side last month.

The example here is saying that the entity called "New York police" is looking for this man... in the other version, they're really talking about a few members of that group, the officers... the entire police force is not doing weightlifting... just a subset.